# get unique strings inside the list of each row python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
                                dt  ... contains
0        2021-03-19 14:59:49+00:00  ...     [up]
1        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       []
2        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       []
3        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       []
4        2021-03-19 14:59:52+00:00  ...       []
                            ...  ...      ...
1624153  2021-07-30 08:53:30+00:00  ...    [buy, buy, buy]
```

for the column contains I want to have unique strings inside of each list like this

```
                                dt  ... contains
0        2021-03-19 14:59:49+00:00  ...     [up]
1        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       []
2        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       []
3        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       []
4        2021-03-19 14:59:52+00:00  ...       []
                            ...  ...      ...
1624153  2021-07-30 08:53:30+00:00  ...    [buy]
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the order matter? And are the values python list or the string representation of the list?

Comment: order doesn't matter I tried using set but it didn't really worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the values in the list doesn't matter, just convert them to `set` then back to `list`:

```py
df['contains']=df['contains'].apply(set).apply(list)

# You can also use a single apply with lambda
# df['contains']=df['contains'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

If the order matters, you can create a helper function to return the list of unique values only, then `apply` it on the column:

```py
def getUnique(x):
    new = []
    for i in x:
        if i not in new:
            new.append(i)
    return new

df['contains'] = df['contains'].apply(getUnique)
```

Comment: also, how would you count how many words are in each list?

Comment: Unique count or just the count?

Comment: now I have a table with unique words and I just want to count how many words are in each list for each row

Comment: Then just use `df['contains'].apply(len)`